# iPhone Simulator, CFServerConection error?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Even with the simplest app (i.e no code, just labels) I get this warning in the system:console (not the Xcode one). I would guess its nothing to worry about, but just wanted to check to make sure?

```
SpringBoard[20558] Unable to create CFServerConnection. 
Telephony state may be incorrect.
```

I am running iPhone-SDK_3, Xcode 3.2.1, Mac_SL_10.6.2

much appreciated

gary

Comment: After a little more searching I am now pretty convinced that this and the open_handle_to_dylib_path 128 Byte memory leak when running "Leaks" are not problems/issues created by myself. I will keep an eye out for answers but for now will ignore them.

Comment: If your application still runs then I'm pretty sure it's ok...I'm too lazy but you should make sure those versions are the latest.Other than that I'm not sure....Good Luck!